# Objects in html not linked

Tags: html, css, href

Social media buttons are not links even though the code shows proper linked objects:

```
<li class="facebook" title="" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Facebook">   
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers"></a>
</li>
```

Comment: Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You should really read the "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" page first.**

Ok so, This link it's not outputting noting, because you didn't specified nothing inside of it to be outputted, at least one letter should be inside of it

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers"> A </a>
```

This will output the letter  [A](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  as a link. Anything you want to be linked should be inside of the `<a>` tag. Another example using an image as a link:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers">
    <img src="random-image.png" alt="test" height="50" width="100">
</a>
```

**Learn more about [a tag here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp)**